# Cache busting images that are fetched use query params

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, caching

I'm getting an image from a url source using query parameters such as:

www.server.com/get?img.jpg

But when the server changes the image, I can't get the latest copy because the image is cached. Most of the answers here on stackoverflow say add a query param for cache busting, but this doesn't work in this case. Tried:

www.server.com/get?img.png&id=1123

Any thoughts/recommendations? Thanks

Edit: The number after id= is random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases the query parameters are implied to *always change*. If you simply add `&id=1123` that will change nothing.

Try adding `&t=nnnn` with nnnn equal to, say, the current time in seconds.

Or if you generate the link on the same server, better still, use for nnnn the *modification time of the image* in seconds, or as a timestamp:

```
?img.png&t=2019-07-04.17.03.22
```

## UPDATE

You're saying that somehow

```
 http://www.server.com/get?img.png&id=1
```

and

```
 http://www.server.com/get?img.png&id=2
```

are being treated by the browser as the same image. I find this difficult to accept, because it would be (among other things) a security flaw - it means that, say, `get?report.pdf&user=whoknows&password=whatever` might end up downloading `get?report.pdf&user=realuser&password=realpassword` without need to supply real login information the second time.

Totally not saying it's your fault (as a developer I found myself often in your exact situation), but someone here seems to have overdone it somewhere. The problems are how to pinpoint where, and what can you do, if anything, with the tools and access you were given.

Why **the server** might be doing this is explained the easiest: the server, or some caching system in front of it, strips extra parameters. So you can ask id=x273y3 as much as you like, that information never reaches the server and can't make it do anything. It would be interesting to know what the use case for this was.

In some, limited cases you might get it done through a ugly hack - if you request `12345/../img.png` instead of `img.png`, and path parsing is done just in the right way, then the cache layer might not cache the request and yet the server still reply with the newer image. But it's a **brittle** hack because lots of legitimate changes in the server architecture might end up breaking it completely, resulting in no image being sent at all.

If you're battling with server side caching then you'd better try and add the appropriate [no-cache pragmas to the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) itself. The reason many use the extra parameter hack is because, due to long-standing abuse by clients, several cache servers can be, and often are, configured to ignore those headers.

Especially if someone went as far as parameter stripping, they should have endeavoured to properly support cache directives instead.

(On the other hand, if you've got a server that ignores *both* legitimate headers and request hacks, you've a pretty solid case that whatever happens is on their heads).

Otherwise, what might be happening is that the *client* believes it can cache the resource because this got sent with specific resource headers (ETag, etc.) and cache revalidation doesn't complete properly because of client/server incomprehensions, which also happens quite often. You should record a full set of conversations and post them here, to help circumscribe the problem:

- headers of the first request to an image
- headers of the reply
- headers of the request to an image that meanwhile changed
- headers of the reply to that

It could also be something very simple, for example the server actually replies with a fixed 302 that strips extra parameters. Then it is the new URL that gets cached:

GET /get?img.png&...
   302 Location: http://static-images.server.com/images/img.png

This could be due to a too thorough Rewrite-Rule by an Apache Server rewrite engine, for example, where "\?(.*.(png|jpg|gif))" is taken from the source request and rewritten to "NewLocation/$1". In such a case another **brittle** workaround would be to request `/get?img.png?t=12345.png`, with two ?'s, to trick the rewrite engine into capturing img.png?t=12345 instead of just img, thus including the cache busting.

The proper, if lengthier, remediation however is to have the rewrite people and the cache people talk to each other and collaborate instead of working at odds.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, the numbers i put are random but still cached